# Can't cleanup whitespace and \n chars in dict:keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, removing-whitespace

filling dictionaries in python3 that contains string like

```
'  \n                    \n                      \n                        \n                          \n   '
```

It's not possible for me to remove whitespaces and line breaks. Every solution I've found contains using method `.rstrip()` or something like `replace(' ', '')`  in dict.

Or:

```
for key, value in dict.items():
    dict[key] = value.rstrip()
```

it results in

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
```

That doesn't work. Any solutions out there?

I'm using Python 3.7

Comment: You're calling `rstrip` on the value, not the key. `new_dict = {key.rstrip(): value for key, value in old_dict.items()}` or similar. Rebuild the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use rstrip() for every value your dict, you can use a forloop:

```
   templist = []
   myDict = {'hi', 'this \n'}

   # removes the '\n' 
   for element in myDict:
      templist.append(element.rstrip('\n'))
      #print(element)
```